# how can i make a file with specific size in a bit time?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, makefile

when i use of "truncate -s" for make a file with 10 Gigabyte size , must wait minimum 2 minutes until that's make .
is there any function in Linux or bash command for rapidly make a file with 10gig cap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `fallocate`, it can be used to allocate files of arbitrary sizes very quickly:

```
$ fallocate -l 10G ./largefile
$ ls -lh ./largefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 10G Nov 18 11:29 largefile
```

---

Another method which is considered a bit older but should be supported if `fallocate` fails is to use `dd`:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=largefile bs=16384 count=0 seek=634K
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.00393638 s, 0.0kB/s

$ ls -lh ./largefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 10G Nov 18 12:00 largefile
```

Comment: have an error "fallocate: fallocate failed: Operation not supported"

Comment: Where are you running the command? This operation might not be supported on some systems (Docker is a notable example). I've added another method to my answer now.

Comment: I would recommend `bs=16384` at least for `dd` and a large `count=` value; and don't forget to `sync`

Comment: i now running on terminal , for first time it`s OK and for second time that try again find-out have fail by this error "fallocate: fallocate failed: Operation not supported"

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch: I added a block size of 1 out of laziness with calculating the seek value!  I will edit my answer to have a larget block size now.  As for `count=`, in most circumstances yes I agree. However by adding a larger `count=` value we actually copy blocks, making the command much slower.  As there was no description saying that any data is needed, simply seeking will allocate the space quickly as requested.  I am less familar with `sync` so if you could explain that would be great!

Comment: this is fail, because "count" when is zero you can see space allocated on partition didn`t change. you can see that via "df -h" and see zero space allocated and capacity dont change when you use of "count=0" in "dd"

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to create random file with random size

> dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat bs=10G seek=1 count=1

thanks for helping ("th3ant" and "Basile Starynkevitch")